# How to set up SVN for subversioning

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-7, tortoisesvn

I have a VPS server with Windows 7, on that server I have placed my Asp.net c# web application. Now how would I do the set up with SVN so that I can check in and check out code from my personal computer?.

**NOTE : this is Tortoise SVN**

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is to install [VisualSVNServer](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) on the machine that you're using as the server, then TortoiseSVN on the one that you're using for the developer workstations.
After you install VisualSVNServer, create a repository and it'll show you the URL to the repository, that you can then plug into Tortoise on the dev workstation.

Then add your C# code to the repository using Tortoise, and you're all set.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is to read the [Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/), as you'll need to have a better understanding of subversion to run a server. It's not terribly difficult, a lot depends on whether you need access to the repository from other computers. If not, you set up a local file based repository without using a server at all. Again, this is all well covered in book.

Comment: I will have two computers accessing it (both from different locations)